# What does Antimonotonicity and monotonicity constraint mean?

Tags: database, data-structures, data-mining

I have looked through the web for this answer and what I get is a similar definition for both of them. This is what I found:

> Monotone constraints possess the following property. If an itemset S violates a monotone constraint C, then any of its subsets also violates C. Equivalently, all supersets of an itemset satisfying a monotone constraint C also satisfy C (i.e., C is upward closed).  [Monotone](https://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007%2F978-0-387-39940-9_5048)
>
> Anti-monotone constraints possess the following nice property. If an itemset S satisfies an anti-monotone constraint C, then all of its subsets also satisfy C (i.e., C is downward closed). Equivalently, any superset of an itemset violating an anti-monotone constraint C also violates C. [Anti-monotone](https://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007%2F978-0-387-39940-9_5046)

Quoting the definitions in the links:

> A constraint C is monotone if and only if for all itemsets S and S′:
>   if S ⊇ S′ and S violates C, then S′ violates C.
>
> A constraint C is anti-monotone if and only if for all itemsets S and S′:
>   if S ⊇ S′and S satisfies C, then S′ satisfies C.

Can anyone please explain it to me what's the difference between them? Preferably with an example.

Comment: They look to me, not as similar, but complementary defintions.

Comment: How is that? _If an itemset S violates a monotone constraint C, then any of its subsets also violates C_ and _any superset of an itemset violating an anti-monotone constraint C also violates C_

Aren't they mean same?

Comment: Thanks a lot. That made it clear. Can you write is as answer so that I can mark it as solved?

Comment: Why the C tag?  This does not appear to be related to 'The C Programming Language'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the first definition, if S violates C, a superset of it *might not* also violate C but a subset *must*... If S satisfies C, a superset of it *must* also satisfy C but a subset *might not*.

The second definition is the other way around... if S violates C, a superset of it *must* also violate C but a subset *might not*... and if S satisfies C, a superset of it *might not* also satisfy C but a subset *must*.

Answer (score 1):

I had to format the example (first para) as a code block so that I could post. Apologies for the inconvenience.

*The two statements are **not** the same.*

### Explanation

According to the first definition, lets write "if S violates C, then S′ violates C" as (A -> B) which automatically implies (not B -> not A) which is the other form of the statement.

If you look at the second definition carefully, it states (not A -> not B) which automatically implies (B -> A) (which again is the other form of the definition).

(A -> B) does not necessarily imply (B -> A) so the two statements are different.

---

### Example

```
For an example. Consider-  
C1 = Sum of elements is greater than 5  
C2 = Sum of elements is at most 5  
U(universe) = Set of non-negative real numbers
```

In case of C1,
If S violates C1, then S' obviously violates C1 as well (S being a superset of S')
Eg. S = {1, 2}, S' = {2}
Hence C1 is monotonic.

In case of C2,
If S satisfies C2, then S' obviously satisfies C2 as well (S being a superset of S')
Eg. S = {1, 2}, S' = {2}
Hence C2 is anti-monotonic.